# Scroll to top arrow is hidden on html, body 100% height

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have implemented a scroll to top arrow using Jquery, and its working perfectly. But my problem is when I set **body, html to 100% height** it hides itself.

[Check this fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/Lomf13tm/6/)

**Html is as follows,**

```
<body>

    <main id="top">
        ........
        main content goes here
        ....
    </main>

    <!-- goto top arrow -->
    <a href="#top" class="goto-top">Top</a>

</body>
```

**CSS**

```
body, html {
    overflow-x: hidden;
    height: 100%; /* when I remove this, it works */
}

main {
    height:100%;
    position: relative;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
.goto-top {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 40px;
    width: 40px;
    bottom: 20px;
    right: 20px;
    position: fixed;
    border-radius:50%;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
    opacity:0;
    z-index:999;
    background:#CCCCCC;
    visibility: hidden;
    color:#111111;
}
```

**When I remove 100% height from html,body element, It works perfectly. I am totally confused. What should be the CSS for .goto-top, html and body?**

**Note:
I wanted to keep body,html height to 100% (Its required - not min-height)**

Comment: Can you make a plunker with the page? I tried to and I don't see the problem you're talking about.

Comment: Show your JS code.

Comment: @master565 check the fiddle

Comment: @makshh check the fiddle

Comment: The problem is that you have two scrollbars with your code (because of 100% height on html tag) and when you scroll you only scroll `main` div instead of whole page.

Comment: @makshh in my actual website, there seems only one scrollbar even on 100% height... but my actual problem is with visibility of Scroll to top arrow

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/Lomf13tm/2/ Two scrollbars on your fiddle, if you have one you have to have something else in your code.

Comment: @makshh actually for demo purpose I have added hieght:1000px to main class, remove it you will see only one scrollbar...

Comment: I viewed the website locally, and removing height: 100% didn't fix it. The only way I ever saw the button was by removing any of the transition code that made it fade from invisible to visible.

Comment: @master565 check back the fiddle again, I have updated it; and scroll to the bottom to see scroll to top arrow... its working... (but sadly without height:100%)

Comment: You can't scroll your whole page if you have 100% height on html and body.

Comment: @SaurabhSonawane Check this updated fiddle out: https://jsfiddle.net/Lomf13tm/8/ - hope it gives you some insight into the issue. I've added in a `console.log` to output the value of the `scrollTop()` reference as well.

Comment: I tested your fiddle, and I discovered that the $(window).scroll() function is never called if body,html is set to 100% height. That's what you need to figure out: Why isn't $(window).scroll() being called?

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove `overflow : hidden`; on the `body` see the code below :)

```js
var offset = 300, /* visible when reach */
  offset_opacity = 1200, /* opacity reduced when reach */
  scroll_top_duration = 700,
  $back_to_top = $('.goto-top');
     //hide or show the "back to top" link
  $(window).scroll(function(){
   ( $(this).scrollTop() > offset ) ? $back_to_top.addClass('goto-is-visible') : $back_to_top.removeClass('goto-is-visible goto-fade-out');
   if( $(this).scrollTop() > offset_opacity ) { 
    $back_to_top.addClass('goto-fade-out');
   }
  });
  //smooth scroll to top
  $back_to_top.on('click', function(event){
   event.preventDefault();
   $('body,html').animate({
    scrollTop: 0 ,
     }, scroll_top_duration
   );
  });
```

```css
body, html {
    height : 100%;
}

main {
    height:100%;
    position: relative;
    overflow-y: auto;
    height:2000px
}
.goto-top {
    display: inline-block;
 height: 40px;
    width: 40px;
    bottom: 20px;
    right: 20px;
    position: fixed;
 padding-top:11px;
 text-align:center;
    border-radius:50%;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
    opacity:0;
    -webkit-transition: opacity .3s 0s, visibility 0s .3s;
       -moz-transition: opacity .3s 0s, visibility 0s .3s;
            transition: opacity .3s 0s, visibility 0s .3s;
    z-index:999;
 background:#CCCCCC;
 visibility: hidden;
 color:#111111;}
.goto-top.goto-is-visible, .goto-top.goto-fade-out, .no-touch .goto-top:hover {
    -webkit-transition: opacity .3s 0s, visibility 0s 0s;
       -moz-transition: opacity .3s 0s, visibility 0s 0s;
            transition: opacity .3s 0s, visibility 0s 0s;}
.goto-top.goto-is-visible {
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;}
.goto-top.goto-fade-out {
    opacity: .8;}
.no-touch .goto-top:hover,.goto-top:hover {
 background:#FFFFFF}
.goto-top.goto-hide{
 -webkit-transition:all 0.5s ease-in-out;
         transition:all 0.5s ease-in-out;
 visibility:hidden;} 
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
.goto-top {
    right: 40px;
    bottom: 40px;}
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<main id="top">scroll below</main>

    <!-- goto top arrow -->
    <a href="#top" class="goto-top">Top</a>
```

Comment: Hi, I know its working without overflow hidden. But in my case, I have used OFF-Canvas navigation menu, there I must use overflow:hidden property.
Thanks for sharing the snippet, but do you have any other alternative to play with height property?